# Variable without name: ${''}

Tags: php

So [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are existing. Meaning that this is working

```
$a = 'test';
$$a = 'Hello';
echo ${'test'}; //outputs 'Hello'
```

But now I've come across some rather strange code using a variable without a name:

```
function test(&$numRows) {
    $numRows = 5;
    echo ' -- done test';
}

$value = 0;
test($value);
echo ' -- result is '.$value;

test(${''}); //variable without name
```

[http://ideone.com/gTvayV Code fiddle](http://ideone.com/gTvayV)

Output of this is:

> -- done test -- result is 5 -- done test

That means, the code is not crashing.

Now my question is: what exactly happens if `$numRows` value is changed when the parameter is a variable without name? Will the value be written into nirvana? Is that the PHP variable equivalent to `/dev/null`?
 I wasn't able to find anything specific about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is: what exactly happens if $numRows value is changed
>   when the parameter is a variable without name?

There's no such thing as a variable without name, an empty string in PHP is a totally valid name.

Maybe I'm wrong, but in PHP, all varibles can be accessed by their names (or more precisely, the string representation of their name), and since an empty string is still a string, it counts as a valid name.

Think about variables like an array key-value pair. You can create an array key with an empty string:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[''] = 'appul';
var_dump($arr['']); // prints: string(5) "appul"
$arr[''] = 'ponka';
var_dump($arr['']); // prints: string(5) "ponka"
```

Whenever you access `$arr['']`, you address the same value.

You can access all variables as a string using the $GLOBAL variable too, so you can examine what happens to your "nameless" variable:

```
${''} = 'ponka';
var_dump($GLOBALS['']); // prints: string(5) "ponka"
${''} = 'appul';
var_dump($GLOBALS['']); // prints: string(5) "appul"
```

> Will the value be written into nirvana? Is that the PHP variable equivalent to /dev/null? I wasn't able to find anything specific about this.

No, it doesn't go to nirvana, it sits quietly in the global space, and it's a little bit trickier to access it, but otherways, it's a normal variable like any others.

Comment: Why is it trickier to access? You can still use `var_dump(${''})` or even `$var=''; var_dump($$var);`.

Comment: well, because you can't access it without typing that extra braces and apostrophe... `$_;` compared to `${''};` is three more extra characters! :D You also cannot use `$;` in itself... Anyways, thanks for accepting my answer, it was an interesting question!

Comment: Ah ok, so just because the extra typing :). But why your acces via `$GLOBAL`? When `${''}` is defined inside a function, it is not inside the globals. I just want to get behind your intentions there.

Comment: Blame the `&` operator in the function. Since the parameter is "called by reference", it initializes the variable when you call it. The same happens when you type `${''} = 'something';` or `$a = "anything";`. You don't need to initialize the variable before assigning a value to it.

Comment: Oh I forgot: my intentions with $GLOBALS was to find out where did the variable went. :D It's a nice way to check all your existing vars.

Answer (score 2):

`${''}` is a valid variable which name happens to be an empty string. If you have never set it before, it is undefined.

```
var_dump(isset(${''}));   // if you have never set it before, it is undefined.
```

You don't see any error because you disabled the NOTICE error message.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo ${''}; // Notice: Undefined variable:
```

You can set it like this:

```
${''} = 10;
echo ${''};  // shows 10
```

Comment: So `${''}` is a valid variable declaration and an empty string is a valid variable name? I've updated the Ideone fiddle: http://ideone.com/tLsOfr and it is really set to the correct value. EDIT: The code in the question does not do an echo to `${''}` and because of that didn't show a notice.